# Get values from a map in apex

Tags: apex, map

I have a map passed as parameter of an apex method. In this method I need to get the values of the map. Here is the apex method :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String manageFilters(Map<String, Object> lines){
    System.debug('### lines : ' + lines);
    System.debug('### lines.values() : ' + lines.values());

    for(String key : lines.keySet()){
        System.debug('### lines.get(key) : ' + lines.get(key));
        System.debug('### >>> ' + lines.get(key));

    }

    return null;
}
```

The map `lines` is not null and contains some values, here is what I can see in the system debug of lines :

> {0={FieldName=AccountId, ObjectName=Opportunity, Operator=<, Value=dfg}}

(Potentially, there could be more than one value)

My question is, how can I get, for example, the value of the 'ObjectName' or the value of the 'FieldName' of this map ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use a Map for this:

```
public static String manageFilters(Map<String, Object> lines){
    System.debug('### lines : ' + lines);
    System.debug('### lines.values() : ' + lines.values());

    for(String key : lines.keySet()){
        System.debug('### lines.get(key) : ' + lines.get(key));
        System.debug('### >>> ' + lines.get(key));
        Map<Object, Object> test = (Map<Object, Object>)lines.get(key);
        System.debug('### test ' + test);
        System.debug('### test ' + test.get('ObjectName'));
    }

    return null;
}
```